# Losing points whenever I downvote somebody

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Why is it that I lose a point every time I downvote somebody else's comment or question? I've downvoted three so far (all for good reason) and have lost three points as a result.

Comment: Note that you only lose a point for downvoting an answer. You don't lose points for downvoting a question, and it is impossible to downvote a comment.

Comment: For the first 5 minutes I thought this was AdamMosheh who asked because of the gravitar :) I'm just curious: what prompted you to choose that picture of Rashi script Aleph?

Comment: Hard to say. I've been using this as my avatar everywhere I go for about six or seven years now. I think it has a beautiful look to it, and while I might have originally chosen it because of various kabbalistic connotations, it's also come to remind me of a painting by Matisse that I particularly like. Not the most "kosher" of explanations perhaps, but there you have it :)

Comment: By the way, I'm referring to this one, at the top of the page: http://smithkleingallery.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/competition-in-art.html

Comment: Certainly not the answer I was expecting but interesting nonetheless!

Answer (score 8):

So that you'll think twice before doing it.

Comment: Seems a little odd to me, that's all. Some answers *should* be downvoted, though I don't much see the point in ever doing so again.

Comment: That's the point, you should really feel that the answer needs to be downloaded in order to do it.

Comment: @ShimonbM That's why it is so little rep that is lost. Losing even the smallest bit makes you think, but in the end it's such a minor loss on your total points that it almost doesn't matter; plus we're here for quality not prestige.

Comment: @DoubleAA: While true, points are not only for prestige, but also to unlock functionality.

Comment: True, but again, it is really a very small percentage of points lost. And functionality is only useful on a functioning site.

Comment: Don't mistake me: I'm not trying to "compete" with anybody for points :) It just seems weird to me to be effectively penalised, however nominally so, when there's no reward allocated for boosting somebody else's point count. The principle makes sense; mainly, I asked because I wanted to be sure that that's what I was losing points for and not for having gone about downvoting somebody incorrectly.